# Override ASP.NET forms authentication for a single page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

In our ASP.NET MVC application, we automatically redirect users to a log-on page via the `<authentication>` section of `<system.web>` when they attempt to access an authorized-only page.  The problem is that one action in the middle of the application, designed to be used by a tool, needs to return a straight-up HTTP 401 response on bad access.  How can I return a real HTTP 401 code *without* the redirect for this specific action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution works, although I'm not at all sure it's optimal:

```
public class HttpAuthenticationRequiredResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = 401;
        response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"whatever\"");
        response.Flush();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

You can then return the above result instead of an HttpUnauthorizedResult to generate the required 401 code.  This feels quite klugy to me, however.

Answer (score 4):

You can have separate `<system.web>` sections for separate paths. Here's an example:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Foo/Bar.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="GoodGuys" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In this case, the page "Foo/Bar.aspx" is allowed to folks with the GoodGuys role, but denied to all others.

In your case, you might want to allow all without authentication:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Foo/Bar.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None" />
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If this were straight-up ASP.NET, that would work, but I'm unclear how to use that technique with ASP.NET MVC.  The problem is that the should-return-401 URLs are at myapp/{rout parameter}/tool; there's no way to specify that in system.web, even if I wanted to.

Comment: Although this works for the authorization element, it doesn't work for authentication - I get the following error:

An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

Comment: I get the same error as Ben Laan. I am struggling with FormsAuthentication. It works as intended, but for one page on which some ajax requests happen, I don't want the  401-code to be overridden by a 302 to end up going to the loginpage. The execution should just end with the status code I put on the Response.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar case where I needed to return back something that triggered an undesired redirect (basically a message about how authentication failed and it was redirecting to the login screen without the error information).

This solved the problem:

```
Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```