# JQuery AJAX post to asp.net webmethod never getting called?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, webmethod

I am trying to send data from my javascript to an aspx webmethod with ajax. the Success option of ajax post is fired but my web method never getting called.
the javascript code is:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../About.aspx/GetWFData',
    data: "{sendData: '" + 5 + "'}",
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Bravo");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

and the webmethod in the code behind is:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetWFData(string sendData)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello");
    }
```

Comment: your json isn't valid. does ASP require it to be? you also forgot to set the contentType.

Comment: When i set the content type attribute i get this error "unauthorised 401"
could you give an example of valid json

Comment: `{"foo":"bar"}` would be valid. All keys must be wrapped in double quotes, and strings must be wrapped in double quotes. It's better to not manually create JSON, instead, use the built-in method. `JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'})` will return `{"foo":"bar"}`(as a string)

Comment: i changed the[ data : JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'}),] but still same issue??

Comment: did you add teh contentType?

Comment: i just added the content type[contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",] 
and i get this error msg [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)]

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Anonymous or Windows?

Comment: i am using webforms authentication

Comment: i even made this change in the web config
             <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
              <!--<deny users="?" />-->
               </authorization>

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117192/asp-net-web-service-inside-forms-authentication-application) has an accepted answer that seems to be related to the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code to see if it works.

```
var params = '{sendData:' + values + '}';
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../About.aspx/GetWFData',
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Bravo");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And refer to http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/ for more info. Try to disable request validation on a page.http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

Comment: the status code is Ok.
how to get the return value of my webmethod in the ajax sucess method
to check if the web method is fired or not?

Comment: From the chrome developper tool it seems that the response i was getting  from calling the web method is the whole page!!