# Calling .net web service behind webform authentication page from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, form-authentication

I am trying to call a web service that is located on a web server that requires web form authentication

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "http://SomeIPAddressThatIDontWantToShare/WebServices/GetServerData.asmx/GetOPCHist_Last4h",
                    data: { OPCName: OPCName_Passed, OPCTable: OPCTable_Passed },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                            T1.push([new Date(element.DateAndTime).getTime(), element.T1]);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(request.status + ' ' + request.responseText);
                    }
                })
```

However when doing so it always hits the error state with a state of "0" and nothing for the responseText. I manually authenticated on the browser before hitting the page.

So the question is, do I have to do web form authentication from javascript, and if so how?

Also is this error even related to web form authentication or is status of 0 possibly something totally different.

I verified I can access that webservice once I log in from a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is under webforms protection, you have to, of course, login first.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117192/asp-net-web-service-inside-forms-authentication-application) to try to remove webforms protection for your ws.
Or you can try [this one](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/dbd724e9-78f0-4a05-adfb-190d151103b2.aspx) to work within webforms.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, while leaving the web service outside of webform protection will not work for us the second solution works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!